# jQuery Image Annotation

Tags: plugin-recommendation, jquery

I'm bascially looking for something that lets visitors to my page comment on photos.
When they hover over the photo the image notes will load.
Best would be if those notes would also show up in the comment-list with a thumbnail of the commented photo next to the comment.

I know it's possible. 
I've seen it [here](http://www.dannychoo.com/post/en/26061/A+Week+in+Tokyo+64.html).
I only could find 2 [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/image-annotation) (which are pretty much the same anyways) in the Wordpress Plugin Dabatase. 
However, after months of trying and even asking here for advice, I have to give up as these plugins just don't work for me.

There seem to be other options out there. 
When I googled, I found that there is a jquery-image-annotation thingie, though I couldn't find any further information about it. As I don't know too much about javascript, I wouldn't be able to write something like that myself anyways.

[This](http://shibuya246.com/2011/01/29/naruto-bridge-shikoku/) seems to be something similar at least. This person is obviously using Wordpress, so I was wondering if that is a plugin as well. I looked at the scripts that he's using but couldn't figure out what exactly he's using for the image notes.

So, basically I was wondering if it's possible at all to create an image annotation for my users in Wordpress and if there are any other plugins you know of that do something similar?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question specifically, I recommend reading my post on galleries and attachment handling in WordPress. It should help you understand the deeper structure and hopefully help you figure out how to do this: http://ottopress.com/2011/photo-gallery-primer/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look at it, but hope for more recommendations, too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking for two features here:

1. Image annotation
2. Image comments

You [referenced a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/demon-image-annotation/) for the first, and WordPress supports the second out of the box!

As another choice, in the last link you provided, that person is using Flickr to handle their annotations and comments. This is another great option if you don't mind the content coexisting on Flickr. There are many [Flickr plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/flickr), but [here is a solid one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tantan-flickr/) that I know supports both annotations and comments. I'm sure there are at least 20 options, and with a little trial and error I bet you'll find exactly what you're looking for in a flickr plugin.

I hope this puts you on the right path to finally setting this up!